# Is it possible to differentiate between landscape left and right in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a view that I want to look differently for landscape left and right, and I'd prefer not to have to deal with rotating all the subviews programatically. However, I don't see the option to different between landscape left and right in xcode. Am I just missing a switch or button somewhere, or is this not possible at all?

For clarity, I know you can do this programmatically using UIDeviceOrientation, but I prefer to keep all view layout work in my storyboards.

Comment: You mean Xcode 9? Anyway, I don't think anything such exist, unfortunately.

Comment: Well at the time I was using xcode 8, but it doesn't look like it exists in xcode 9 either :( Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this functionality does not exist as of Xcode 9.2